# How do I display a folder that exists in the file system, but not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory, restore

I have a Java web project in Eclipse Luna.  In the project, I can see the WEB-INF folder and under that folder there's supposedly a lib folder (you can see it in the file system).

The question is how do I make the lib folder visible in my project?

Thanks a million!  I have been troubleshooting for the last 4 hours!! :(

Comment: If its Maven project than lib folder will not be visible

Comment: Sorry, it's actually an GAE Endpoint project created by the Android project.  I tried to troubleshoot by creating a new endpoint and the WEB-INF/lib is there.  Don't know how it got delete from Eclipse, but it's still in the folder on the file system.  Very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse Dynamic web-project then it will display under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

If your project is a maven project and you converted it into eclipse project using `mvn  eclipse:eclipse` command,  then It will not show lib folder under WEB-INF directory. Still you can see your war file containing lib folder under WEB-INF directory.

If you want to see your third party jars in eclipse then goto Package Explorer view then you will be able to see all external jars inside `Referenced Libraries`.